# bootstrap navbar brand centering

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'd like to center the `brand` name inside the `navbar` between a bunch of links (i.e., 2 links to it's left and 2 to it's right).
The thing is that I want to also make a menu for when the `navbar` is `collapse`ed and make it like so that the `brand` WON'T appear in the `dropdown list`.

https://jsfiddle.net/u471wydy/

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

Please checkout my solution at **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/yaLdZN?editors=1100)**

Hope it helps you.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

    </div>
    <a class="navbar-brand navbar-nav" href="{% url 'chat:index' %}">Chaty</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>          
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  z-index: 3;
}
ul.nav.navbar-nav {
  margin: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
  }
 ul.nav.navbar-nav {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. Your solution does seem to work but I would like a solution that won't require me to add an "invisible space"... And also the whole navbar becomes a link to the home page.

Comment: I have updated my solution without the "invisible space". [Codepen](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/yaLdZN?editors=1100) link also updated. Now I hope your issue has been resolved.